# C# - How to make this thread wait?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

I have this:

```
public class ServiceLibrary
{
    public object result = null;
    private bool finished = false;

    public void testar()
    {
       ServiceReference.Service1SoapClient serviceReference = new ServiceReference.Service1SoapClient();
       serviceReference.updateUserCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.updateUserCompletedEventArgs>(serviceReference_updateUserCompleted);
       serviceReference.updateUserAsync();
       ManualResetEvent m = new ManualResetEvent(true);
        
    }

    void serviceReference_updateUserCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.updateUserCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        result = e.Result;
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

and outside I have this:

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ServiceLibrary serviceLibrary = new ServiceLibrary();
    serviceLibrary.testar();
    lblCharName.Text = Convert.ToString(serviceLibrary.result);
    
}
```

**What should I do to the thread wait, so when I assign the text, it contains the value, please?
Thank you**

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use your `ManualResetEvent`? or create a fresh one.

I believe the `ManualResetEvent` is thread safe....

```
public class ServiceLibrary
{
    public object result = null;
    private bool finished = false;
    public ManualResetEvent m;

    public void testar()
    {
       ServiceReference.Service1SoapClient serviceReference = new ServiceReference.Service1SoapClient();
       serviceReference.updateUserCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.updateUserCompletedEventArgs>(serviceReference_updateUserCompleted);
       serviceReference.updateUserAsync();
       m = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    void serviceReference_updateUserCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.updateUserCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        result = e.Result;
        finished = true;
        m.Set();
    }
}
```

```
public Home()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ServiceLibrary serviceLibrary = new ServiceLibrary();
    serviceLibrary.testar();

    serviceLibrary.m.WaitOne();

    lblCharName.Text = Convert.ToString(serviceLibrary.result);
}
```

Comment: I know... the `ManualResetEvent` is REALLY usefull.... I'm not sure why it wouldn't have worked. Did you make sure you set the initial state to `false`?

Comment: This is the way to go.  Not sure why it didn't work for you, but this is the standard way of achieving this.

Comment: Guys, when I call serviceLibrary.manualResetEvent.WaitOne(); outside, then it waits forever...
yes the initial state is false.
Any ideia?

Comment: I used another thing to work, I passed as argument to the method, so I could change what I wanted,

Answer (score 0):

Make your ManualResetEvent variable m a member variable of the class.
and inside your threaded method: serviceReference_updateUserCompleted, make sure to call
m.WaitOne();

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
public class ServiceLibrary
{
  public object result = null;

  public void testar()
  {
     var serviceReference = new ServiceReference.Service1SoapClient();
     using(var m = new ManualResetEvent(false))
     {
       Action<object, ServiceReference.updateUserCompletedEventArgs> handler = 
       (sender, e) => 
       {
         result = e.Result;
         m.Set();
       };
       serviceReference.updateUserCompleted += handler;
       serviceReference.updateUserAsync();
       m.WaitOne();
       serviceReference.updateUserCompleted -= handler;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have a similar situation.  I use a technique called *polling*, which is exactly what it sounds like.  It may or may not be appropriate for you depending on your situation.

```
public class ServiceLibrary
{
public object result = null;
private bool finished = false;

public void testar()
{
   ServiceReference.Service1SoapClient serviceReference = new ServiceReference.Service1SoapClient();
   serviceReference.updateUserCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.updateUserCompletedEventArgs>(serviceReference_updateUserCompleted);
   serviceReference.updateUserAsync();
   ManualResetEvent m = new ManualResetEvent(true);

while !finished
 Thread.Sleep(100);

doStuffWithResult(result);
}

void serviceReference_updateUserCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.updateUserCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    result = e.Result;
    finished = true;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear that the caller wants to force the service call to be synchronous (which is what your change would do).

Comment: What else could he have meant by saying that he wants it to wait until the value is available?

Comment: (-1) should never use a sleep for this kind of thing. Just wastes the users and the processors time.